# What is the word for afternoon?

Tags: colloquial-language

I found the terms gogo and hirusugi listed. Is gogo based on the entire afternoon period and hirusugi based on midday?

Comment: You should at least show what you've learnt so far from your research. If you need an example, see [this](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18356/5010). "The most used word" largely depends on the context, and you're likely to get an insufficient answer if your question is insufficient. And what's this "colloquial-language" tag? Is this mean it's important to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We mostly use "午後"（gogo）in any situation.